# Loss of visa refusal letter

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I applied for a UK visa in February and April 2017 to travel with my sister. However my application was initially refused, stating I might become an illegal immigrant. Once I sent further documents to prove that I will not, they rejected saying I do not have enough money. Again I sent proof that I am being sponsored by my sister and that all expenses on this trip are paid. They rejected that my source of money is not clear. I couldn't go with my sister.

Presently I have been offered a seat in a Master's course in New Zealand and I need to apply for a visa. I however do not have all copies of previous refusals. I do have my visa application numbers.

My question is, how can I get a copy of the visa refusal letter at the earliest?

Can someone please help?

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to include refusal copies?

Comment: For Ireland, I saw around 63 applications of 1900 applications in the visa application status published, rejected in a single month, on the grounds that Visa refusal letters of previous visa application to any country being not attached, even after the declaration. That is very very bad